# Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable

Tags: twig

When I try to display this twig I get this error;

> Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable.

On the line where it shows; `<th>Bestelordernummer:</th> <td>{{ontvangst.bestelling.id}} </td>` 
I have no idea where this is coming from

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}
    <style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 8px;
    }


    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    </style>
        <h1>Overzicht van zendingnummer</h1>
        <h2>
        <a href="{{ path('alleontvangst',{}) }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Terug naar alle ontvangsten</button></a></h2>
        <ul>
        {% for ontvangst in ontvangsten %}
                    <table>
                    <th>Zendingnummer:</th> <td>{{ontvangst.zendingnummer}}</td>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                    <th>Datum ontvangst:</th> <td>{{ontvangst.datumOntvangst|date("d/m/Y")}} </td>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                    <th>Bestelordernummer:</th> <td>{{ontvangst.bestelling.id}} </td>
                    </table>
            <table>
                    <th>Naam Leverancier:</th> <td>{{ontvangst.naamleverancier}} </td>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Artikelnummer</th>
                    <th>Omschrijving</th>
                    <th>Hoeveelheid</th>
                    <th>Kwaliteit</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ontvangst.artikel.artikelnummer}}</td>
                    <td>{{ontvangst.omschrijving}}</td>
                    <td>{{ontvangst.hoeveelheid}}</td>
                    <td>{{ontvangst.keuringseis}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
        {% endfor %}
        <ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: how do you fetch data and pass them to your view? Does every ontvangst has bestelling?

Comment: Yeah they do have that! That is just the weird part. Because it is working for " artikelnummer"  later on. But when I added "id" I got this error. while they are configed the same

Comment: @Colin, which answer was the correct one? Can you click the check ark besides the correct answer that you used?

Answer (score 4):

@Aenadon is correct. You need to check if `ontvangst.bestelling` is null. You can code that in Twig something like this:

```
<table>
    <th>Bestelordernummer:</th>
    <td>
        {% if ontvangst.bestelling is not null %}
            {{ontvangst.bestelling.id}}
        {% else %}
            N/A
        {% endif %}
    </td>
</table>
```

You can modify your code as needed.

Answer (score 2):

`ontvangst.bestelling.id`

Error message says "cannot get attribute id on null variable". This means that the `bestelling` on object `ontvangst` is null. Make sure that `bestelling` is not null and then the issue is gone.

Comment: It's late. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The solution of @alvin works good. Another solution is to use the `default`twig filter, like this :

```
<table>
    <th>Bestelordernummer:</th>
    <td>
        {{ ontvangst.bestelling.id|default('Your default value here') }}
    </td>
</table>
```

So if bestelling is not define, it will show the default value

Comment: This is a great alternate solution!